# Sqlite timestring convert into %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

timestring = 574173060999555008

query:

```
datetime(‘2001-01-01’,substr(timestring,1,length(timestring )-9 || ‘ seconds’)
```

output:

```
2019-03-13 12:31:00
```

want output:

```
2019-03-14 00:31:00
```

Comment: Please explain the details of your computation. Adding 574173060 seconds to January 1st, 2001 does produce `2019-03-13 12:31:00`.

Comment: Might depend on locale/time zone, since that [date is DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2019.html) in some parts of the world and not in others. That could account for the 1 hour difference. I don't pretend to understand this stuff, but I'll readily admin to being flummoxed by it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference of **12 hours** between your expected output and the actual output.
If this is the result of regional time zone difference you can add the `+12 hours` *modifier* to `datetime()` function at the end to get what you want:

```
datetime('2001-01-01', substr(timestring, 1, length(timestring ) - 9) || ' seconds', '+12 hours')
```

Result:

```
2019-03-14 00:31:00
```